# CSS Responsive background image

Tags: html, css

Good Afternoon Stack!  I need some CSS help.

I have a background image that I want centered with the body of the website.  I want it to look nice and not too blown up, or too small. Here's what I've tried so far.

```
body{
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

#container{
    max-width: 780px;
    background: url('/img/background2.png') #1e1e1e no-repeat 0px 12px fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    color: #d1d1d1;
}
```

It almost works.  When the browser window is full screen, the background image seems to pull to the left.  When the browser window is smaller it fits perfect.  And on a mobile phone like my MotoX using chorme it's blown up really huge instead of looking reasonably scaled.

`background-size: contain;` is even farther from my desired result.

Here's the HTML for ref.  I've also thrown it up on my server http://jasontolhurst.com

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Jason Tolhurst</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container" class="container-fluid">
            <header class="header clearfix">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                        <li>
                            <a target="_blank" href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/4490365/squeegy"><img style="max-width:23px" src="/img/stackoverflow.png" /></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/squeegy06"><img style="max-width:23px" src="/img/github.png" /></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/pub/jason-tolhurst/91/9b/775"><img style="max-width:23px" src="/img/linkedin.png" /></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <h1>Jason Tolhurst</h1>
                        <p class="lead">Professional PHP developer and programming enthusiast</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="content" class="container-fluid">
                <div id="about-me" class="col-md-12">
                    <h2>About Me</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="projects" class="col-md-12">
                    <h2>Projects</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="contact" class="col-md-12">
                    <h2>Contact Me</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro|Droid+Serif|Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/screen.css">

                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>        
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you put the background image on body instead?

Comment: You sound like you would like to have it as ```background-position: 50% 50%;```

Comment: @AmmarCSE we tried that originally and we'd have to use `background-position: center` and though it looked nice at full screen, when you viewed on a smaller window it got a little wierd.

Comment: You could also set up a media query and have the ```background-position``` change depending on browser size.

Comment: @nikkwong How do I do a media query?  I don't know a lot of CSS.

Comment: To better address your question, what exactly do you want? On a large browser you would like the background image centered in the middle of your element and on a small browser—what? Do you want it to show the left hand side of your image (assuming that's the part of the background that looks 'nice' as a background).

Comment: Actually @nikkwong I think you may have solved my issue.  I didn't know about media queries and now I found https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries  I think some tinkering and I might get this working.  Thanks!   If you want to change your answer to that I'll accept it for you.  To add, on a large screen it should be center with the content.  On a small screen it should fill like the content does.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by 'fill', as it looks like it's covering the entire window already at < 800px. Glad I could help! Good luck.

Comment: @Squeegy not an answer, but i would rethink your background design all-together. Text over text doesn't look great.

Comment: @AJcodez thanks.  This is why I'm a programmer and not a designer :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `background-position` to tell the `background-image` *where* to sit as a background. In your case, if you would like the background image directly in the center of the element it's applied to, you want `50% 50%`. Where, `0% 0%` will be position the image relative to the top left hand corner of it's element and `100% 100%` will position the image in the bottom right hand corner of it's element.

So `background-position: 50% 50%;`

It's important to note that using a `media-query` will allow you to apply different CSS display properties/values at different browser sizes. This will allow you to fine-tune a certain CSS property/value to a certain display size.

Read more:

`background-position`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

and

`media-query`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: The background image isn't on the body, but rather the container that the whole website content sits in so this doesn't give me what I want.